# Context is null in onPostExecute in android stuido uisng Java?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, nullpointerexception

I'm having issues getting a recycler view to display text. I'm pretty sure its because context is null

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TextView textView;
private Button button;
//private RecyclerView output2;

@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getItemsButton);
    //make textview scrollable
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    String s1[] = new String[0];
    /*try {
        s1 = new String[]{new deserializeItem().toString()};
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }*/

    //recyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new recyclerAdapter(this, s1);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                String itemText = new DeserializeItem().toString();
                DeserializeItem di = new DeserializeItem();
                di.execute("temp");
                //output.setText(itemText);
                //output2.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class DeserializeItem extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Item>> {
    private Context context;


    @Override
    protected List<Item> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String itemText = "";
            String jsonUrl = "json url here";
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            //Reads data from JSON File and converts it to a string
            InputStream is = new URL(jsonUrl).openStream();
            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
            is.close();

            //Convert json string to array of Item objects
            Item[] items = gson.fromJson(jsonTxt, Item[].class);
            List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

            //Eliminates objects with null and empty item names
            for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].getItemName() == null) {continue;}
                else if (items[i].getItemName().equals("")) {continue;}
                else {itemList.add(items[i]);}
            }

            //Sorts by list ID, then sorts naturally by name
            Comparator<Item> comparator
                    = Comparator.comparing(Item::getListId)
                    .thenComparing(value -> {
                        int indexOf = value.name.indexOf(' ');
                        return Integer.parseInt(value.name.substring(indexOf + 1));
                    });
            Collections.sort(itemList, comparator);
            return itemList;

            //converts items to a string to be returned and displayed.
        /*for (int i=0; i<itemList.size(); i++)
        {
            itemText += itemList.get(i).toString();
        }
        return itemText;*/
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
            //return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> itemList)
    {
        //super.onPostExecute(itemList);
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        //Toast.makeText((MainActivity)context, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String[] itemText = new String[itemList.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<itemList.size(); i++)
        {
            itemText[i] = itemList.get(i).toString();
        }
        if (context != null)
        {
            putDataIntoRecyclerView(itemText);
        }

    /*try
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        Item[] items = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Item[].class);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }*/
    }

    void putDataIntoRecyclerView(String[] itemList)
    {
        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter((MainActivity) context, itemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

recylcerAdapater

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

//String id[], listID[], name[];
String info[];
MainActivity context;
//public recyclerAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], String s3[]){
public RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity ct, String[] s1){
    context = ct;
    info = s1;
}

public <deserializeItem> RecyclerAdapter(deserializeItem deserializeItem, String itemText) {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView1.setText(info[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return info.length;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textView1;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }
}
```

}

I'm not sure if I'm not going about things the correct way or not, but I can't get anything to display in the program. I do know that if I remove

> if (context != null)
> {
> recyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new recyclerAdapter((MainActivity) context, itemText);
> putDataIntoRecyclerView(itemText);
> }

it'll give me a Null Pointer Exception.

Please forgive me if my question isn't well articulated or formatted, I'm pretty new to asking stuff on StackOverflow.

Comment: It complies, but it doesn't display anything. and I'm pretty sure its because context in  recyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new recyclerAdapter(context, itemText) is null

Comment: No its a separate class. Would it make any difference if I put it in MainActivity?

Comment: "Yes its null as you did not assign a value to the variable. Add a constructor for the task with a context as parameter. From where do you call the task?" I'm not totally sure what you mean here?

Comment: Alright I put async into mainactivity and tried to make the code a little more readable and I call execute from onClick

Comment: Its time you tell us if all works as expected.

Comment: I changed all that stuff, but it still doesn't work. Context is still null

Comment: Of course as you did not add a constructor to the task that takes a Context as parameter. Then you would change the call to: DeserializeItem di = new DeserializeItem(MainActivity.this);

Comment: But.... You do not need that context variable and constructor at all as at creating the adapter you could change `(MainActivity) context` to MainActivity.this.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, changing it to MainActivity.this managed to get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Changing `(MainActivity) context` to `MainActivity.this` should resolve this issue.

I reckon that even if this resolves the issue, this is not the best approach to use context. This can result into context leaking.

You should rather create a listener to get callback of the items from Async task to the activity. By doing this, all your context and recycler view related stuff will reside in Activity as it should be.

For Ex.

```
interface DataCallback{
    public void getData(List<Data> data);
}
```

And from Async task:

```
listener.getData(data);
```